# Common /Cross browser CSS

Tags: html, css

I designed a web page using my own css. I ran them on Google Chrome and Firefox. Web pages looked like same and no problem. But in IE, all pages are very ugly. I have used many css styles which do much more. But those css s don't work in IE. If I use basic css,then I ll have to use more images and do more things to get the same look( I want to save time to work with functions in client side and server, and don't like to spend time designing). also If other available css frameworks are used (jQuery), then useless styles and images will be loaded which can cause to slow the web page loading.  I used css reset style sheet.but it didn't solve my issue.
I want to make my  pages nice in IE as in Chrome and FF and do less with css.And not to use more css frameworks? What Can I do for this?

Should I have to do all css works again which works for IE (spending time..:( )?
**Edit:** I looked into sources of many web site which are in my web site's type. They also have used basic css and used many images for a better look. but I want to focus on functioning and deslike to spend time editing images and dor much more with desigining.

Comment: what version of IE browser are you referring to? is it css3 properties? Give us example of css that shows different in IE

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I have used css for border shadings,rounders, gradients, shadows. I used jQuery. Some animations are not smooth as in Chrome and FF.

Comment: jQuery is not a CSS framework.

Comment: I meant jquery:- this http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tool called  pie.htc which allows you to use css3 properties in IE.
It dosent fix everything but surely helps, and all you need to do is a simple CSS property.
Learn more here :
http://css3pie.com/

Comment: that link is so useful. Thanks for that.

Comment: You are absolutely PERFECT !!!